# Display values from Laravel Many-to-Many Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I am having trouble with displaying data from a Many-To-Many Laravel Pivot table. The set-up of the pivot table is:

characteristic_answers

```
id - user_id - characteristic_id - characteristic_option_id
1      130           5                        6
1      130           5                        7
1      130           1                        2
```

The model characteristic_answer is:

```
/**
 * Get the characteristic for the charactersticanswer.
 */
public function characteristic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Characteristic::class);
}

/**
 * Get the option for the charactersticanswer.
 */
public function characteristicOption()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CharacteristicOption::class);
}
```

The view which I have now to loop through the characteristic name and answers is:

```
@foreach($user->characteristicAnswers as $characteristicAnswer)
      @if(!$characteristicAnswer->characteristic->multiple)
            <dt>{{$characteristicAnswer->characteristic->name}}</dt>
            <dd>{{$characteristicAnswer->characteristicOption->name}}</dd>
      @elseif($characteristicAnswer->characteristic->multiple)
            <dt>{{$characteristicAnswer->characteristic->name}}</dt>
            <dd>{{$characteristicAnswer->characteristicOption->name}}</dd>
      @endif
@endforeach
```

But this displays the answers like:

**The only.
->King.

She took down a jar from.
->ME,' said the.

She waited for some.
->However, she did so.

She waited for some.
->Alice herself.

She waited for some.
->Alice again..

Test kenmerk
->Nee**

As you can see the She waited for some. characteristic is repeated 4 times because there are three answers. I want the characteristic name to be shown once and the three answers in an array after the characteristic name. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'belongsToMany' relation. Refer to [Laravel Many to Many Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

And pivot table should contain the ids of the two table table1_id and table2_id (table name followed by underscore and id).

And for unique value use of DISTINCT should work.

I hope this will work for you. Cheers.